# Why watcher does not run?

Tags: vue.js

I have the following data property called `selector`, which I set its initial value in `mounted()` since it is an HTML element that also has a bit of delay due to loading I set its value in a `setTimeout()`. Then whenever I select a different option its `value` should obviously change. And this change should we watched. Right now the `watcher` does not seem to work and I can't see why. Can someone help?

My data propery:

```
data() {
    return {
      selector: " ",
}}
```

my watcher:

```
watch: {
    // whenever selector changes, this function will run
    selector: function(newSelection) {
        console.log("in watcher", newSelection);
      $(".page-item a").each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() == ">") $(this).text(" ");
        else if ($(this).text() == ">>") $(this).text(" ");
        else if ($(this).text() == "<") $(this).text(" ");
        else if ($(this).text() == "<<") $(this).text(" ");
      });
    }
  },
```

and `mounted()`

```
 mounted() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document
        .getElementsByTagName("select")[0]
        .setAttribute("id", "VueTables__limit");
      this.selector = document.getElementById("VueTables__limit").value;
      console.log("in mounted", this.selector);
    }, 2000);
  }
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="form-group form-inline pull-right VueTables__limit">
  <div class="VueTables__limit-field">
  <label for="VueTables__limit" class="">Records:</label> 
  <select name="limit" id="VueTables__limit" class="form-control"> 
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
  <option value="50">50</option></select></div></div>
```

Comment: Use an arrow function in your `setTimeout()`. When you use a `function() { ... }`, you lose your `this` context

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: even after doing the change to the `setTimeout()` I only get the initial value logged to the console, and not when the value changes.

Comment: I see no other code that changes the value of `selector`

Comment: well, that it is in the HTML, I can paste it as well, but it is just a traditional select element.

Comment: I just updated.

Comment: Setting `this.selector` to the element value (as you have done in `mounted`) does not bind it forever, it only happens once; it will not change `this.selector` when you select a new option. You should be binding the `<select>` value using something like `v-model`. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select

Comment: yeah, I just realized it, however, I can't directly do that since the HTML is a compiled version of an npm module. is there a way to add that the same way I added the id ?

Answer (score 1):

Update your `mouted` function:

```
mounted() {
    var self = this; //save the ref of 'this'
    setTimeout(function() {
      document
        .getElementsByTagName("select")[0]
        .setAttribute("id", "VueTables__limit");
      self.selector = document.getElementById("VueTables__limit").value;
      console.log("in mounted", this.selector);
    }, 2000);
  }
```

Comment: as I commented above, even after doing the change to the setTimeout() I only get the initial value logged to the console, and not every time the value changes.

Comment: because you did not bind `select` and `option`  nodes to your viewModel.check the [Vue Doc](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select) to see how to bind your selection to viewModel

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you need to setup initial data value and call some methods during component's lifecycle, use watcher with `immediate: true`. Next, default value could be just empty string `""` no need to add space. And the last, why you use jQuery, when you have vue? Don't get it